# ASP.NET Core - having mTLS and OAuth2 at the same time

Tags: asp.net-core, security, bearer-token, mtls

I have ASP.NET Core RESTful APIs and protect them with JWT token issued from Azure Active Directory. Any client who wants to call the endpoints should first acquire a valid JWT token from the AAD and send that as a Bearer token. My API internally should call an external API (internal to the organisation) to query some information and return it to the user. The external API requires mTLS as its security protocol.

**My questions**

1. Can I still have my Bearer authentication scheme against my APIs and at the same time have mTLS enabled in my API so it can communicate with the third API?
2. From my understanding, in TLS which mTLS is an extension of it, the client should verify the server's certificate. Does that mean, with every incoming request I should check if it's presenting the certificate? If so, then what would happen to the Bearer authentication scheme then?

In my head, I was hoping that I can just append the certificate to the requests against the third-party API and that should be it but based on question number 2 I seem to be wrong about it.

I'm a bit lost here and appreciate any advice on this.